# Android DiskLruCache supported versions?

Tags: android, android-lru-cache

I have a simply question. I'm developing an aplication wich loads images from a remote server (via http). I'm looking for a good way to cache this photos and I've read about LruCache and DiskLruCache. I'm very interested in the second one because It offers things like, if someone calls you and the app closes, this cache will allow you to take back the photos without connect anywhere, while LruCache does that only while the app is opened. So here is my question:
Will Android 2.3.X phones work good with DiskLruCache?? I want my app working in "old" phones too, not only phones over Android 3.0. 
Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html. Check the heading Use a Memory Cache in the link. (also available in the Support Library for use back to API Level 4)

Comment: Ok, thank's a lot. I have now realized that says pretty big LEVEL 4 in the documentation. Sorry, my mistake. Silly question